My laptop turned off while running memory diagnostic test. Is this harmful to my laptop?
I was doing memory diagnostic test on my laptop with this command on run mdsched.exe. I forgot to put the charger while doing the test, and my laptop battery discharged while doing the test due to not plugging the charger.
Is it harmful that my laptop have turned off while doing the test due to the not plugging the charger?

Not harmful but a symptom a something wrong with the hardware.

@changanauto, the battery was already low so it completely discharged while doing the test

If so, nothing to worry about. That said you should avoid such scenario. Any hardware diagnostics should be done with a power supply.

If you didn't witness it turning off (safely or otherwise) and you haven't specifically disabled the feature, windows will typically shut down the computer when a critical battery level is reached. So it's likely it just turned itself off?

Power off during memory diagnostic will not harm anything.
